# Sharepoint and Cross-Site Lookup

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

I have this scenario

I want to build two sharepoint 2007 sites. One for customers info and the other for products and

customers orders.

Now the problem is that in the second site I need to reference the customers info from the first site but unfortunately sharepoint doesnot provide out of the box cross-site lookup.

I did some search and found custom cross-site fields and used one but when I upgraded the

site to sharepoint 2010 this custom field was not compatible and the upgrade wizard said it could not be upgraded.

so what is the solution for this ? is it to merge the two sites so that I can use the standard lookup feature or is there any workaround for this ?

please if any body has faced such a scenario, share the solution with me ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sites are in the same site collection, the out of the box lookup field can work across sites. The browser UI does not show it, but you can set LookupWebId on the field through either the api or a list template.

Given your specific scenario though, it would probably make more sense to set up the customers as users (possibly via a custom membership provider) and just use a standard user field.

Comment: Thanks Tom
that is what I did finally
got it from here
http://www.alexbruett.net/?p=153&cpage=1#comment-251
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to create new custom field type for fetching customers info from the first site and it can be added your list.

The below site can help you:
http://vspug.com/nicksevens/2007/08/31/create-custom-field-types-for-sharepoint/